# How to handle JSON with namespaces with JsonPath

Tags: java, jsonpath

I'm having trouble using JsonPath for checking json with namespaces in front of fields. I haven't been able to find anything from google or looking through existing issues or the documentation. I haven't been able to get anything to work. I have the following snippet of json:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "bb:list" : [ {
      "id" : "id",
      "label" : "label",
      "description" : "description",
      "timezone" : "timezone",
      "postalAddress" : {
        "addressCountry" : "country",
        "addressLocality" : "city",
        "addressRegion" : "state",
        "postalCode" : "postal code",
        "streetAddress" : "street address"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to check the bb:list field to see how many items are in it. This JsonPath expression does not seem to work:

"$._embedded.bb:list"

If I remove the "bb:" then using this works "$._embedded.list" so it's the bb: that it doesn't seem to like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem I was having was not with the JsonPath expression, or JsonPath at all. Spring Boot was bringing in JsonPath so it all compiled and seemed fine, but at runtime, it just wasn't working for whatever reason. I explicitly added JsonPath to my dependency list and it magically started working.

EDIT: So the above fix was not permanent. It turns out that a transient dependency of JsonPath - Json-smart is using a newer version than the version the version that is being pulled in by Spring-test (by several of it's transient dependencies). 
I fixed it by adding an exclusion for json-smart from the spring-starter-test dependency:

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
    exclude group: 'json-smart'
}
```